# Testing a website from Linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, monitoring

I am looking for a tool to test a website from a Linux command line.

From the output, I need to know the http response (status codes) but also benchmark the time it takes to download the different elements of the site.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you found, looked at, or are considering (suitable / not suitable) so far?

Comment: None of these answers sound very good to me.  You still have to wait ages for a negative

Answer (score 46):

You can try `wget` with `-p` option:

```
wget -p http://site.com
```

It will tell you how long it takes to download each element and the return codes for each request.

Comment: `wget -p URL -O /dev/null`

Comment: From [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options): `p`, `--page-requisites`: get all images, etc. needed to display HTML page

Comment: Use the command from @Fedir RYKHTIK in order to not pollute your current dir

Comment: You can get just the **Total wall clock time** by appending stderr to stdout `2>&1` and grepping it: `wget --page-requisites --output-document /dev/null URL 2>&1 | grep Total`

Answer (score 9):

Please see Apache Benchmark:

[Apache Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)

This should give you an overview of your page's performance.

Comment: Apache benckmark cannot be use for this since it is an external source, in fact it is youtube video playlist. We are monitoring the access to this ressource. TY

Comment: I don't see why you can't use ab; like wget in the next answer, it will work as long as the URL of your site is accessible from the machine where you're runinng the benchmarking tool.

Comment: Apache benchmark is not restricted to local resources, it's meant to be a full performance measuring tool (including network latency, i/o, etc).

Comment: Good to know, I will evaluate this option, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to look at the following options of `curl`:

- `--write-out` - displays any of several time-related variables
- `--trace-time` - Prepends a time stamp to each trace or verbose  line
- `--verbose`
- `--include` - (HTTP)  Include  the  HTTP-header in the output.
- `--trace-ascii <file>` - Enables a full trace dump of all  incoming  and  outgoing  data,
  including descriptive information

And the following option of `wget`:

- `--timestamping` - Turn on time-stamping

Comment: `curl --trace-ascii <file> --trace-time -o /dev/null <url>` was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Selenium and Curl are good options depending on what your goal is.  Also, a utility that I've come to like quite a bit is `twill`. More information is available at http://twill.idyll.org/.

It's nice as it has it's own little specialized language for filling out forms, validating links, and checking response codes. Since it's just Python code, you can easily import the libraries and automate your tests yourself if you'd like to do something different.

Answer (score 2):

Use curl to get the header for the page, and time the process:

```
time curl -I http://yourpage.com | grep HTTP
```

wrap that in a while loop and you're good to go. The same way you can check for all elements if you know the URL.

Answer (score 1):

try a commandline tool called 'siege'
as instructed [here](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3936526/Load-Testing-and-Benchmarking-With-Siege.htm)

Comment: That's not what he's asking for. and you're also 3 years late =)

Answer (score 1):

What tool you choose depends on what you want to measure and the complexity of the site.

If the behaviour of the site is dependent on cookies (e.g. user needs to login) then ab / curl / wget (described in other answers) will not suffice. One solution is to use [http::recorder / www::mechanize](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/04/recorder.html).

All the data you are asking for is in your webserver logs - and a simple awk script will return it in a more readable form.

> benchmark the time it takes to download the different elements of the site.

This is a very poor indicator of performance (although it is useful for monitoring the health of a production system). With the exception of large/slow resources such as bulky reports, iso images, multimedia files the perception of performance has got very little to do with the time taken to process a single request - and its really difficult to measure this accurately (simply adding %D to your apache log appears to solve the problem but ignores TCP handshakes, SSL negotiation, caching effects, DNS lookup times).

A better solution is to use something like [Boomerang](https://github.com/yahoo/boomerang/) - but that runs in a Javascript capable browser. While this gives a better indicator of perceived performance than tracking individual HTTP requests, it relies on browser events to derive a value for the performance - but peceived performance is all about the time taken for the viewport to render (again there are tools for this - have a look at the filmstrip tools in [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/)).

There is also the argument about measuring the performance actually delivered to users of the site (RUM) vs synthetic testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to need something bigger then curl and/or wget, there is also [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I think for running performance test you can try [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/). You can record your test using the built in proxy. It also runs in text mode, local or distributed. You can save your results in csv or xml format. If using xml format you can also store the content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

For checking headers, I like [`httpie`](https://httpie.org/) ([docs](https://httpie.org/doc)).

### Installation

```
pip install httpie --user
```

### Usage

```
$ http -h http://serverfault.com/q/124952/113899
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 0
Cache-Control: private
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 198
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 10:01:06 GMT
Location: http://serverfault.com/questions/124952/testing-a-website-from-linux-command-line
Set-Cookie: prov=392298d9-103e-7dfc-5b55-8738be46cf3b; domain=.serverfault.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid: 07a25de4-6e16-4aa8-acfc-12b1bbbc6180
X-Served-By: cache-hhn1543-HHN
X-Timer: S1483696865.976259,VS0,VE187
```